# Nested Form Model in Rails not saving items added with jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following Ryan Bate's RailsCast ([#197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)) for Nested Model Forms.

If I submit a form that has 3 fields added in the controller:

```
3.times { @prof.experiences.build }
```

...they save properly. If the field, however, is added via jQuery, it isn't saved.

Has anyone else had experience with this sort of problem before?

EDIT: HTML Generated without jQuery:

```
<div class="fields">
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td>Position Title:</td>
<td><input id="applicant_profile_experiences_attributes_0_title" name="applicant_profile[experiences_attributes][0][title]" size="30" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Employer:</td>
<td><input id="applicant_profile_experiences_attributes_0_employer" name="applicant_profile[experiences_attributes][0][employer]" size="30" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Responsibilities</td>
<td><textarea cols="40" id="applicant_profile_experiences_attributes_0_description" name="applicant_profile[experiences_attributes][0][description]" rows="4"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Start Date:</td>
<td><select id="experience_from_date_1i" name="experience[from_date(1i)]">
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
<p><input id="applicant_profile_experiences_attributes_0__destroy" name="applicant_profile[experiences_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false"><a href="#" onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;">Remove</a></p>
</div>
```

Code added with jQuery:

```
<div class="fields">
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>Position Title:</td>
        <td><input id="applicant_profile_experiences_attributes_1366407307283_title" name="applicant_profile[experiences_attributes][1366407307283][title]" size="30" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Employer:</td>
        <td><input id="applicant_profile_experiences_attributes_1366407307283_employer" name="applicant_profile[experiences_attributes][1366407307283][employer]" size="30" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Responsibilities</td>
        <td><textarea cols="40" id="applicant_profile_experiences_attributes_1366407307283_description" name="applicant_profile[experiences_attributes][1366407307283][description]" rows="4"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Start Date:</td>
        <td><select id="experience_from_date_1i" name="experience[from_date(1i)]">
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<!-- removed big date list -->
</select>
</td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>
<p><input id="applicant_profile_experiences_attributes_1366407307283__destroy" name="applicant_profile[experiences_attributes][1366407307283][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false"><a href="#" onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;">Remove</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML that is being generated with and without jquery?

Comment: Hmmm. I was thinking that maybe the input elements generated by jquery had a typo or something. But they seem correct to me.

Comment: Are the fields being added inside the form tag?

Comment: Yep - it appears as if anything generated by jQuery isn't being passed as a parameter. If they were generated in the controller, they get passed. Everything seems right - it's driving me crazy.

Comment: @TheSciz did you see the post request in CDT or firebug?

Comment: @shishirmk Yes, in CDT. It's not sending the added fields.